# How to share data between two web pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-webpages

Im trying working on a web app project and trying to figure out how to display my answer on the second web page.

I have put a a text box on my first webpage and have corrected the coding of my application as I have received the correct answers in the textbox after I have debugged it.

Ideally I want to remove this textbox and want my answers which I managed to display on my textbox displayed on a label in the next webpage. Here is the calculation part of my code;

```
var cost = ((int)duration.TotalMinutes) * 0.35m;
                txtCost.Text = cost.ToString("c");
```

I'd like to make my answer appear in my second webpage and not have it displayed in the first. I have tried using `Session["Cost"] = cost;` on the button click event handler of the first webpage `double cost = (double)(Session["Cost"]);
                lblDisplay.Text = cost.ToString("c");`
and this on the second webpage but every time I Debug it and run I always get $0.00 displayed on my label. Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: Your main question says two web applications and scenario you mentioned is for two web pages. May be more/complete code can get you some help.

Comment: Indeed, are we talking about separate web applications or different pages within one and the same web application? Also, is this WebForms or MVC application?

Comment: Multi page application guys..sorry about that...two web pages only

Answer (score 0):

Sharing value between two views in MVC application, try following

```
// To save into the Cache    
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache["CostKey"] = cost;

// To retrieve Cache Value
var cachedValue = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache["CostKey"] as double;
```

For Session State, have a look at this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: May you explain what the "CostKey" name is. because mine says that it doesnt exist in the context

Comment: You can give any name. CostKey is just a name and it will be used when you retrieve your value. I have modified my answer. Key name suppose to be of string type. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET WebForms application, you can pass data around in various ways:

1. Cache

   See the Learning Curve answer for examples.
   However, the object put in the cache is not guaranteed to be found again if the server experiences memory shortage or alike. The ASP.NET manages the cache and evicts objects on its own to maintain memory availability. This is in contrast with `ApplicationState` and `SessionState` where the objects are kept until they are removed manually, or the `Application` ends or `Session` expires.
2. Session and Application states

   You can put any object in the [`SessionState` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) and retrieve it elsewhere in your code. However, you need to cast it appropriately as the `SessionState` accepts `object`-s. E.g. if you store a number, when you retrieving it, you must do the casting yourself, just as you already did it.
   The reason it doesn't work, is perhaps you're trying to retrieve it from within another user's `SessionState`. Yes, the `SessionState` is a per-user structure. If you need to add the value as from one device and use it on another, [use `ApplicationState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94xkskdf.aspx):

   ```
   Application["cost"] = cost;
   ```
3. Redirecting Response

   Using this technique, you could force the browser to request another page from the server and specify the full query string, including the variables you need. E.g. :

   ```
   var destination = Server.UrlEncode("/someOtherPage.aspx?cost=34.65");
   Response.Redirect(destination);
   ```

   As an alternative, you can use `Server.Transfer("someOtherPage.aspx")` to save the roundtrip. However, in that case, the browser doesn't change the address in the address bar so the user is misled that she browses one page, but in fact, it is the `someOtherPage.aspx`.